# AD0-E709 - Adobe Commerce Developer Expert

Tags: magento2, adobe-commerce

An Adobe Commerce developer is asked to restrict access onboth the admin menu item Custom_Reports: :Financial and the admin pagecustomreport/financial/index attached to the menu.
The developer has added the resource Customreports/financial in etc/ael.xml. and the following code on
etc/adninhtml/menu.xml :

[image]

Given that const ADMIN_RESOURCE was NOT set on the controller of customreports-financial/index and
the secret key is not enabled in the URL which users can access the page?

A. Only admin users with Custom_Reports::financial resource access.

B. Only admin users with ALL resources access.

C. All admin users.

What is the correct answer for the above question?

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer must be **C. All admin users.**

If you take a look in `\Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction`, when the Action is dispatched this simple method is checked:

```php
/**
 * Determines whether current user is allowed to access Action
 *
 * @return bool
 */
protected function _isAllowed()
{
    return $this->_authorization->isAllowed(static::ADMIN_RESOURCE);
}
```

As `ADMIN_RESOURCE` is not set in the custom Action, it allows all users:

```php
/**
 * Authorization level of a basic admin session
 */
const ADMIN_RESOURCE = 'Magento_Backend::admin';
```